# How to validate column position in webtable using Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I got  5 columns in a table: Name, Birth year, Gender, Occupation and Salary.

Task is to check whether occupation column title is located
at **2nd place** from the right side.

```
public void positionofOccupation() {
    List <WebElement> ch = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class='header']"));
    for (int i = ch.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        WebElement ch1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@class='header'])[" + i + "]");
        if (ch1.getText().trim().contains("Occupation")) {
            System.out.println("Occupation position is at " + i + " column);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Occupation position is wrong and is at " + i + " column);
        }
    }
}
```

It's printing me a **4** instead of **2** when that "if" condition is **true**.  I need to print **2** because test case is about **2nd position** not 4th position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working exactly as written. The desired text is found in the 4th column, not the second. You are decrementing the column counter from the max column, `for (int i = ch.size(); i > 0; i--)`, but not subtracting the found column index from the max column index if you want to find the position from the rightmost column.

I think what you are looking for is

```
public void positionofOccupation() {
    List<WebElement> ch = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class='header']"));
    for (int i = ch.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        WebElement ch1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@class='header'])[" + i + "]"));
        if (ch1.getText().trim().contains("Occupation")) {
            Integer columnFromRight = ch.size() - i + 1;
            System.out.println("Occupation position is " + columnFromRight + " columns from the right");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Occupation position is wrong and is at " + i + " column");
        }
    }
}
```

Rather than using sysout prints to the log, I would suggest you investigate JUnit, TestNG, or some other assert library. It will make your work much easier. Your `if else` and sysout messages will turn into just

```
assertEquals(2, columnFromRight, "Verify 'Occupation' column is second from right");
```

...and you'll get a report of what tests passed/failed rather than having to look through all the logs.